# Email group is not receiving email sent SSIS configuration file

Tags: sql-server, ssis, smtp, etl

I am using various email addresses to send process success emails. All the email addresses receiving emails accept the newly added group.DBAs@abc.com is not receiving email. It's a group. all others are receiving emails.
sample:

```xml
<Configuration ValueType="String" 
           Path="\Package.Variables[User::EmailTo].Properties[Value]" 
           ConfiguredType="Property">

<ConfiguredValue>
tim@abc.com;DBAs@abc.com;kl@abc.com;hj@abc.com
</ConfiguredValue>

</Configuration>

</DTSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Ask your mail admin team to ensure your mail server will allow the group to be addressed via SMTP: (1) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cd4e3fdd-1bb9-403e-bb3b-cc863e86b8da/sending-email-to-a-distribution-list-having-more-than-one-member-through-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices (2) https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/ssis-send-mail-task-togroup